# How do I avoid this busy-wait?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

```
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    if(children == null){
        new SalesRequest().execute(); // runs in other thread which 
                                      // initialises children with some value.
        while(children == null){
            // I'm doin this to avoid null pointer Exception.
            // So it comes out of the loop only when childern 
            // gets initialised.
        }
    }
    return children.length;
}
```

But I'm not satisfied with the way I'm handling this. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Down voters plz add comments too.. I can change the question if i'm not clear.. I'm just seeking some help..

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but can you please explain what are you trying to achieve on the above code?

Comment: @zengr.. Its actually android code.. I need to update the UI based on the server response. and i don't have any control over the method since its a cal back. So i have Overriden it to initialise some variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a CountDownLatch to wait for the other thread to complete.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html

Answer (score 3):

There are a multiple of possible solutions for this issue. The most elegant way is as Eric mentioned above, CountDownLatch.
Here is how you could proceed:

```
// Lock to signal Children are created
CountDownLatch childrenReady = new CountDownLatch(1/*wait for one signal*/);
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    if(children == null){
        SalesRequest request = new SalesRequest(childrenReady /*pass on this lock to worker thread*/);
        request().execute(); // runs in other thread which 
                                      // initialises children with some value.
        childrenReady.await();        // Wait until salesRequest finishes
        while(children == null){
            // I'm doin this to avoid null pointer Exception.
            // So it comes out of the loop only when childern 
            // gets initialised.
        }
    }
    return children.length;
}
```

In SalesRequest.execute method, you could have the following:

```
// Populate and create children structure of the calling object
// When done, signal to callee that we have finished creating children 
childrenReady.countDown(); // This will release the calling thread into the while loop
```

Also, make sure you are not calling `getChildrenCount()` from the UI thread otherwise your application will hang and will loose its responsiveness until you get an answer from the server.